# using map() instead of for loop

Tags: r

My task is to recreate the result of this for loop by using the `map()` function. Unfortunately, I can't get my head around this.

```
play_roulette <- function(bet, number) {
  draw <- sample(0:36, 1)
  tibble(
    winning_number = draw,
    your_number = number,
    your_bet = bet,
    your_return = if (number == draw) {
      bet * 36
    } else {
      0
    }
  )
}


desired_length <- 10 
list_w_for <- vector(mode = "list", length = desired_length)

for(i in seq_along(list_w_for)){
  list_w_for[[i]] <- play_roulette(bet = 1, number = 5)
}


for_tibble <- bind_rows(list_w_for)
for_tibble
```

My current `map` code:

```
num_vec <- 1:10
bet_vec <- 1
tibble_2c <- tibble(x= bet_vec, y= num_vec)

map_dfc( tibble_2c,
    play_roulette(bet = x, number = y))
```

Comment: `replicate(10, play_roulette(1, 5))` may be helpful. If everything is constant, then `play_roulette2 = function (bet, number, sims){draws = sample(0:36, sims, TRUE); tibble(draws, number, bet, return = (number == bet) * bet)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to call the function 10 times, since the iterator i is not used inside of the function.

```
# use *_dfr to row_bind the result
map_dfr(
   # call the function ten times
   1:10, 
   # note that .x, the default iterator in map, is not needed inside of the function
   ~play_roulette(bet = 1, number = 5))
```